# How to measure smoothness of inputs over outputs?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, data-mining, smoothing

I know similar questions have been asked for time series data. But my question is a little bit different.

Consider that we have input dataset $X \in R^{N \times M}$, where $M$ is the dimension of inputs and $N$ is the number of samples. The output can be more than one dimension. Therefore, the output of our dataset is $Y \in R^{N \times T}$, where $T$ is the dimension of outputs. The problem refers to multitarget regression in the literature.

My question: Is there any criteria to measure the smoothness or the roughness of this dataset?

My definition for smoothness: Small change on inputs does not change outputs significantly.

Also, if there is a method for just $T=1$, I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

Curvature based penalty terms have been suggested for regularising RBF and MLP neural networks, see e.g. [Bishop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/bishop-curvature93.pdf) (equation 8).  Note however your mileage may vary (hint: what contsraints apply to the gaps between datapoints?).

Comment: Is curvature-based a method to smooth the dataset or a method to measure the smoothness?

Comment: It is a measure of the smoothness of a fit to the dataset, but that might include a model that exactly interpolates the dataset, which is probably as good as any method of estimating the smoothness of the data itself.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any package or function in r, python or Matlab to measure this criterion?

Comment: Not that I know of.  If there is a package that implements spline fitting, it may have something similar though.